# Preserve CMD output format when redirecting it

Tags: c#, cmd, textbox, output, text-files

Right now I have an app where a user can pass some arguments into a process and get the output in a textbox and/or a textfile. However, the output does get the same format as it would if those processes were run via the command prompt. They are just read line by line and put in without the proper paragraphs and spacing. Is there a way to preserve the original output? Two related functions below:

```
    //function called via a button to write to textbox
    // userInput is the textbox's name
    private void call_Process(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = selectedFilePath;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}", userInput.Text);
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        try
        {
            process.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }

        while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            processOutput.Text += line;
        }
     }



    //function called via button to write to textfile
    private void write_To_File(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfile.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openfile.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openfile.FilterIndex = 1;

        if (openfile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(openfile.FileName);
            tw.WriteLine(processOutput.Text);
            tw.Close();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Use fixed-size font for `processOutput` control and: `processOutput.Text += (line + Environment.NewLine);`.

Comment: Yup that fixed it! Thank you.

Comment: @Igor, consider to post your command as an answer, so the question does not remain open (supposing the OP accepts it then)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the suggestion of @aschipfl:

Use fixed-size font for `processOutput` control and

`processOutput.Text += (line + Environment.NewLine);`